# Storing double up value in an Array using for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

/*IMO I have completed most of the project, but I can't wrap my mind around part with the array. I am supposed to assign the values to it then have it show on screen, as it is doing now when program get run, but it isn't going through the array. Please help its driving me insane.

Assignment:

For this project, you will create a program that asks the user to enter a positive integer value less than 20.  Note that the program will only collect one number from the user.  All other numbers will be generated by the program.

If the user enters a number greater than 20, the user should get an error.

If the user enters a number equal to or less than 20, display the double of each value beginning with 1 up to the selected number (multiply each number by 2), then provide the total of all doubles.

For example, if the user entered the number 5, the following should display:

```
Double up 1 = 2

Double up 2 = 4

Double up 3 = 6

Double up 4 = 8

Double up 5 = 10

Total = 30
```

Minimum Requirements:
• Create a separate class that contains the following methods. Note: This class should be separate and apart from the public class that holds the main method.  1. A method that will accept two parameters: an integer array and a integer variable. 1. The integer variable should hold the value provided by the user.  The array will be used to hold the double up results. 
2. This method should perform the calculations, and store the double up results in the array.  Additionally, the total of all double up values should be calculated using an accumulator variable that is also a private instance variable.
3. You must make sure the calling method gets the changes to the array.  Remember, arrays are passed by reference by default.  This method must use a loop.

2. A separate method that will return (not display) the value stored in the private instance variable called total.

• Create a main method that creates an array and integer variable, as well as an instance of your class.  The main method should then use the instance to call each of the methods of the class, passing the data needed and handling any return data. Display the entire contents of the array and total variable. 
 */

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class project2 {

public static void main(String args[]){

    scores output = new scores();
    output.enterNum();
    output.displayScores();

}

}
class scores
{
    int total;
    int stats[] = new int[20];
    int num1;
    void enterNum()
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 20: ");
        num1 = input.nextInt();

        if(num1<=0 || num1>20)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered a wrong number. Try again.");
            System.out.println("");
            enterNum();
        }   


    }
    void displayScores()
    {
        int b=0;
        int val2=0;
        int total = 0;


        val2=num1*2;


        for(int i=1;b<val2;i++)
        {


            System.out.println(b=i*2);  
            total = total + b;

        // this part.   
        //  stats[i] = b;
        //  System.out.println(stats);
        }

        System.out.println(total);

    }   

}
```

Comment: what exactly a problem?

Comment: Your code is quite confusing. The problem seems to be in thedisplayScores method. The parameter of the for-loop do not make sense. What is the variables b and vak2 supposed to represent?

Comment: Sorry if it is confusing. 
val2=num1*2;  Since Its supposed to double up I assigned num1(what user inputs) * 2 (to double), and assign it to val2. I see now that I could have done this right num1=num1*2; ?  So anyway if you run the program it asks for a number, lets say you enter 5 * 2 = 10. It stars from 2,4,6,8,10 and stops. 
b...I guess I don't need it? i=i*2  would do the same ?

Comment: From the way I read this, your main method should be getting the number from the user as well as do all the printing. The other class should only return the data once the operations are done, yet all of your printing is done by the other class. Another note, you don't need an array of size 20, but rather make it the same size as the number entered by the user (if it in the acceptable range)

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Be clear about your edit comments.

Answer (score 0):

Maljam is right, your for-loop is the issue here.

Your for-loop is messing around with some `int b` that doesn't need to be there. What you want is to add `i*2` to total on each iteration of your loop. Also, you need to modify your for-loop header to check against `i` instead of `b`. I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with the array. It's not needed in this project at all.

Try changing it to something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=val1; i++){
    //stats[i] = i;
    System.out.println("Double up " + i + " = " + 2*i);
    total = total + 2*i; //or total += 2*i;
}
System.out.println("Total: " + total);
```

Comment: Well my professor wants us to use one (it says in the text I posted above).  
;(. 
That's the main issue here. 
So when I add these two lines
       stats[i] = i;
 
       System.out.println(stats);

I get something like this [I@33909752

Comment: Your print statement should be `System.out.println(stats[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class scores {

int total;
int stats[];
int num1;

void enterNum() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 20: ");
    num1 = input.nextInt();

    if (num1 <= 0 || num1 > 20) {
        System.out.println("You entered a wrong number. Try again.");
        System.out.println("");
        enterNum();
    }

}

void displayScores() {
    stats = new int[num1];
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        stats[i] = (i+1) * 2;
        total += stats[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        System.out.println((i+1) + " * 2 = " + stats[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Total: " + total);

}
}
```

Comment: Those 2 for loops could easily be combined into 1

Comment: of course, But I put them for clarification and separation between login and output.